# How to setting limit to show pushpin

Tags: bing-maps

I have a map of bing maps and I use has created pushpin do with double click. And now I want to make limits pushpin only <= 20.

If it has been over the limit point is then automatically pushpin cannot be displayed. Although double click in map.

But I don't understand how to create it. Can you help me? Thanks a lot. Gbu.

My code to show pushpin

```js
   map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), mapOptions);
              Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'dblclick',getLatlng );          
    }

    //show pushpin
    function getLatlng(e) {
    if (e.targetType == "map") 
    {
    var point = new Microsoft.Maps.Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
    var locTemp = e.target.tryPixelToLocation(point); 
    var location = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(locTemp.latitude, locTemp.longitude);
    alert(locTemp.latitude + "&" + locTemp.longitude);
    var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(location, { 'draggable': false });
    map.entities.push(pin);
    alert("Done");
    Microsoft.Maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event)
    {
    }
    // limit pushpin 
    *How to create limit pushpin?*
```

Answer (score 0):

In the getlatlng function you can do a simple check to see how many shapes are on the map. You can get the number of shapes on the map in your application by doing the following:

```
var cnt = map.entities.getLength();
```